# Select locations where the user doesn't have it bound yet from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

User Info

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bob |
| 2 | jane |
| 3 | tom |

Locations

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 |
| 2 | Test2 |
| 3 | Test3 |
| 4 | Test4 |

User Locations

| userID | locationID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

Basically What I am trying to achieve is to pull the location names where the user doesn't have it bound already.

In the above list Bob has 2 locations bounded "test 1" and "test 2" but he doesn't have "test 3" or "test 4" yet. I Only want the data to return test 3 and 4 since those are the only ones Bob doesn't have.

For Jane  She only has Test 3 bounded but none of the remaining 3

Originally I had tried this and it somewhat worked. However Every time another user gets an unbounded location the its removed from the list. I'm not sure how I would add the user ID in all this so it's only specific to that user.

```
SELECT `name` FROM `locations` 
WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `locationID` FROM  `user_locations`)
```

Comment: Basically https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry What's missing? He shows the tables and the attempted query.

Answer (score 1):

Create a cartesain product of the user and locations table (cross join), then using an outer join allows us to find rows that are as yet unmatched in user_locations:

```
select
      user_info.ID AS UserID
    , locations.ID AS locationID
from user_info
cross join locations
left outer join user_locations on user_info.id = user_locations.userid
                              and locations.id = user_locations.locationid
where user_locations.userid IS NULL
and user_info.name = 'bob'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eab5a6/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE user_info(
   id   INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,name VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO user_info(id,name) VALUES (1,'bob');
INSERT INTO user_info(id,name) VALUES (2,'jane');
INSERT INTO user_info(id,name) VALUES (3,'tom');

CREATE TABLE locations(
   id   INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,name VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO locations(id,name) VALUES (1,'Test1');
INSERT INTO locations(id,name) VALUES (2,'Test2');
INSERT INTO locations(id,name) VALUES (3,'Test3');
INSERT INTO locations(id,name) VALUES (4,'Test4');

CREATE TABLE user_locations(
   userID     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,locationID INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO user_locations(userID,locationID) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO user_locations(userID,locationID) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO user_locations(userID,locationID) VALUES (2,3);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      user_info.ID AS UserID
    , locations.ID AS locationID
from user_info
cross join locations
left outer join user_locations on user_info.id = user_locations.userid
                              and locations.id = user_locations.locationid
where user_locations.userid IS NULL
order by 1,2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eab5a6/1/0)**:

```
| UserID | locationID |
|--------|------------|
|      1 |          3 |
|      1 |          4 |
|      2 |          1 |
|      2 |          2 |
|      2 |          4 |
|      3 |          1 |
|      3 |          2 |
|      3 |          3 |
|      3 |          4 |
```

Comment: It did not seem to work, running that query returns everything and repeated again. I actually modified my original query 

   `SELECT name FROM locations
     WHERE id NOT IN (
     SELECT locationID FROM  user_locations WHERE userID = 1
     )`

This seems to do what i'm expecting in only pulling out the location names where the current user doesn't have another location already bound to him

Comment: The technique shown above is very standard for what you are asking. It does work - see the fiddle. Your example data has 3 users, 4 locations = total of 12 combinations. Your example table of combinations has 3 rows, so the number of missing rows is 9. My example returns all 9 rows that do not exist in the user_locations table.

Comment: and if you only want rows related to bob, then include that condition in the where clause